# How to check two arrays, a random generated and user inputed array in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to check each value of two arrays that contain 5 values to see if there are any matches.

For example, a random array of {3,5,2,6,8} and a user generated array of {3,2,2,5,9}. In this case there would be two matches.

The **Goal** of this program is to check a random array and compare it to a user generated array and return the number of matches.

**The Problem**: I am able to generate a random array, but I am stuck on trying to check for any matched numbers and output that number in the main function

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //for time() function
using namespace std;

void generateNumbers(int arrLotto[], int arrSize) {
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    int rnum = (rand() % (10));
    arrLotto[i] = rnum;
    cout << arrLotto[i] << " ";
}
}

int findMatches(const int arrLotto[], const int arrUser[], int arrSize) 
{
int matchCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    if (arrLotto[i] == arrUser[i]) {
        matchCount++;
    }
    return matchCount;
}
}


int main() {

int rnum;
int arrLotto[5];
int arrUser[5];
int arrSize = 5;
int matchCount = findMatches(arrLotto, arrUser, arrSize);

//prompt user for lotto numbers
cout << "Enter your 5 lottery number picks (0-9)\n" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << "Number " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> arrUser[i];
}

//display Lotto numbers
cout << "\nLottery Numbers" << endl;
generateNumbers(arrLotto, arrSize);


//display array user numbers
cout << "\nYour Numbers" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << arrUser[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

//display matches
    cout << "\nYou matched " << matchCount << " numbers" << endl;

    if(matchCount == 5)
    cout << "You are a grand winner" << endl;


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why is there only two matches?  Both arrays have 3 of the same values.

Comment: @NathanOliver ??? That's my problem, I can't check if there are any matches and then output that number of matches

Comment: It's not your problem, I'm just struggling trying to determine the logic.  You state *For example, a random array of {3,5,2,6,8} and a user generated array of {3,2,2,5,9}. In this case there would be two matches* and I would like to know why there are only 2 matches when both arrays contain 3,5 and 2, so there should be 3 matches.  I'm just trying to understand how the code should behave.

Comment: @NathanOliver in order for a match to occur the location matters. Even though 3,5,2 are both contained in each array, only 3 and 2 occur in the same location in both arrays. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues with the code:

- You are calling the `findMatches` function before populating the user inputted array and populating the random generated array.

  So the matches (if any) will be random and unpredictable. Not to mention that your program has undefined behavior due to accessing uninitialized variables.

  Call `findMatches` after you have populated the user inputted array and the random generated array.

  The below statement:

  `int matchCount = findMatches(arrLotto, arrUser, arrSize);`

  should be after the second `for` loop in `main`.
- You should also pass a reference to array instead of the array itself so that you will preserve the randomly generated numbers in the array after the funtion returns. So you have to change the prototype of `generateNumbers` function to this:

  `void generateNumbers(int (&arrLotto)[5], int arrSize)`
- And within the function, you have to return after the completion of the `for` loop and not after the first iteration. So move the return statement

  `return matchCount;`

  after the closing brace of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each of the input arrays into `std::set` (or sort them via `std::sort`). Then you can use set intersection algorithm. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection
If the output is empty, there are no matches and the size of the output indicates number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling findMatches() method before array is populate, so it always return 0 bcz when you call findMatches() method at that time both array are empty.

So the solution is first populate the user attay then call generateNumbers() to populate random array then call  findMatches() then it will give you a perfect count.